# What are the differences between qperf and ping test latency results?

Tags: linux, networking, performance, latency

I am wondering what are the differences between qperf and ping tests latency results. In terms of measuring latency between two servers which tool result could be considered more accurate?

**ping:**

```
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.187/0.308/0.730/0.144 ms
```

**qperf:**

```
tcp_lat:
    latency         =    55.5 us
    msg_rate        =      18 K/sec
    loc_send_bytes  =      18 KB
    loc_recv_bytes  =      18 KB
    loc_send_msgs   =  18,031 
    loc_recv_msgs   =  18,030 
    rem_send_bytes  =      18 KB
    rem_recv_bytes  =      18 KB
    rem_send_msgs   =  18,031 
    rem_recv_msgs   =  18,031
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all which protocols this utils used:

- ping use ICMP protocol
- qperf use TCP protocol

If you need simply check is host accessible use ping.

But not all cases:

- Windows hosts by default disable ICMP echo.
- another network devices can be set up to deny ICMP
- Juniper equipment by default in QOS politics set lowest priority for ICMP traffic, including drop of packets

If you need check latency between hosts and main load will be TCP traffic, qperf will be good choice for this .